# AWS Lambda depleting the SQS queue very slowly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue and a lambda which consume the queue with batch size 10.

**Lambda**

Reserve concurrency = 600

Timeout = 15 minutes

Memory = 640 MB (but using 150-200 MB per execution)

Processing one item comes from the queue takes about 10 seconds.

**SQS**

Messages Available (Visible):   5,310

Messages in Flight (Not Visible):   3,355

Default Visibility Timeout: 20 minutes

With these settings, I'm expecting my Lambda function to be invoked 600 times because as you see the queue is full and there are items to received from the queue. So, the function shouldn't be idle and use all of the available concurrency.

I'm aware of the first 1 minute of burst and later my concurrency will increase every minute until hitting to the limit. But my invocation count is always between 40-80. Never hits to 600 and my queue is depleted very slowly. And (according to logs) almost any of the queue items are failing, so they are not going back to queue again.

What is wrong with my settings?

[image]

EDIT:
Also another chart:
[image]

Increased up for a moment and decreased again..

Comment: Invocations increased up to 580 for a few minutes and drop back to 68.

Comment: What about `Throttles` and `Errors` metrics for your function?